# Double cursor in Skyrim

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

Since I've installed Dawnguard and Hearthfire, when ever I do an <kbd>Alt-Tab</kbd> and come back to the game I get the windows cursor and the game cursor. And both are not sync over each other so it's kind of annoying. How can I fix this bug ?

Comment: This can also occur without these mods installed :/.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Hit <kbd>Esc</kbd> before minimizing Skyrim, that way the Windows cursor won't show up after maximizing the game.

Answer (score 6):

There is now a mod to fix the double-cursor bug: [Double Cursor Fix at Skyrim Nexus](http://skyrim.nexusmods.com/mods/36125/).

Answer (score 0):

#### [OneTweak](http://www.nexusmods.com/skyrim/mods/40706)

The [**OneTweak**](http://www.nexusmods.com/skyrim/mods/40706) mod includes an Alt+Tab double cursor fix. It also allows borderless window mode, dynamic process priority (give Skyrim more CPU priority for better performance), and has a RaceMenu precache killer (prevents crashing).