# How do I get the operating system cursor to disappear in Windowed mode whilst on Crafting menus?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Double cursor in Skyrim](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/90407/double-cursor-in-skyrim)

The white arrow (operating system cursor) shows up at all times whilst playing the game on windowed mode after tabbing out. In screens where the Skyrim cursor is also present, they are both visible.

Solutions like "pressing Esc before you tab out" aren't useful because it won't work whilst in a crafting window. The main use of tabbing out for me is to use web-based tools for Alchemy recipes.

I know there must be a better way of fixing this since I've played the game before on this computer for a whole playthrough without this issue.

Comment: Wait, how is this different from the question you mentioned?

Comment: Because my quesion has more information and is about a more specific situation (in windowed mode) and the solution that was posted and (accepted) does not solve my problem since I can't do it whilst in crafting menus AND it doesn't work whilst windowed. It's not my fault if an incomplete answer was previously accepted.

Comment: I've edited the question to emphasise why it is different.

Comment: If you are not satisfied with an answer to a question that was asked by somebody else you can a) leave a comment b) offer a bounty for a better answer. You can't just post the same question again. Also, I'm playing with windowed mode on and hitting escape before switing windows does help, 100% of the time.

Comment: Agreed - this is a distinct scenario, compared to the alternative question. Behaviour varies from windowed to full-screen mode. [Not sure where that downvote came from.... It's a perfectly legitimate question]

Comment: Does the [mod mentioned in the other question](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/117914/4797) by SevenSidedDie help?

Answer (score 1):

Updated:

In Full-Screen Mode:
 - Click on Skyrim in the taskbar
 - Move the cursor from the very top of the screen (i.e. from the window 'chrome', the outside border) back down into the black area... after a moment or two it will disappear.
 - Alt-Tab away from... and back to the Skyrim window (i.e. cycle through all apps back to Skyrim, via Alt-Tab)

In Windowed Mode:

- Click on title bar of window
- Click inside window

Comment: Are you playing in windowed mode? When I click on Skyrim in the taskbar it immediately activates the window and places my cursor in the center.

Comment: Fair point - I posted before I tested, thinking the windowed solution would be the same as the full-screenl turns out, for me at least, that the solution is simpler....

Comment: Your windowed mode solution doesn't work for me. When I click on the title bar, my cursor is immediately centered in the window again and the game is activated. I don't get a chance to make a second click.

Comment: I'm afraid that, despite my best efforts, I can't replicate your experience - perhaps you can update your post with specifics about your setup - it may depend on specific Windows versions or graphics card drivers...