# Fallout TTW mouse acceleration - unaffected by Fallout_default.ini changes

Tags: technical-issues, fallout-new-vegas, mouse

Following the instructions [here](http://www.nexusmods.com/newvegas/mods/34690/?), I've changed my `Fallout_default.ini` accordingly:

```
[Controls]
bAlwaysRunByDefault=1
bBackground Mouse=0
bBackground Keyboard=1
fForegroundMouseAccelBase=0
fForegroundMouseAccelTop=0
fForegroundMouseBase=0
fForegroundMouseMult=0
```

However, mouse acceleration is still very obviously in effect.

I've tried the following:

- replicated these changes in `\Documents\my games\FalloutNV\Fallout.ini`
- removed `\Documents\my games\FalloutNV\Fallout.ini` (it was not automatically regenerated)

What is the problem?

Comment: Would help if you confirmed in OS settings you are also not employing mouse acceleration.

Comment: @lancnorden Yes, that much should be obvious.

Comment: Have you tried editing FalloutPrefs.ini and Fallout.ini and made sure they're read only again afterwards? I use RFCW but none of these commands are in any of my ini's and I don't have mouse acceleration going on. I can only suggest using NVSE.exe - the Silent Hill dll fix - and the Stutter Remover (that's every thing I can think of as to why I don't have those commands and don't have to deal with mouse acceleration) My rule of thumb is that if you can find a place to put it in any of the ini's: put it in.

Comment: Same thing for [me with Skyrim](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/130866/skyrim-fallout-3-and-new-vegas-major-mouse-issues): the only thing that's in my ini's is bBackground Mouse=0 (although it's also heavily modded)

Comment: @DavidTan No reason to assume what is not stated.

Comment: @Mazura thanks, that didn't solve the problem but gave me an idea to try, and it turns out that mouse acceleration is properly disabled (though it still feels unnaturally floaty/laggy) when running directly through the launcher rather than through Mod Manager. I'll try disabling mods one by one to find out which one is the problem.

Comment: Alright this is weird... it's not any mod that's causing it. The culprit is the application called Mod Organizer; using it to launch the game causes the mouse acceleration. I'm now looking for an alternative to using Mod Organizer...

Comment: I would suggest using [FOMM](http://www.nexusmods.com/newvegas/mods/54991/?tab=2&navtag=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.nexusmods.com%2Fnewvegas%2Fajax%2Fmodfiles%2F%3Fid%3D54991&pUp=1), and set everything to never update: tell Steam not to, and tell the mod *manager* not to update itself or your mods, and once you get it to work, change nothing. Also, don't *ever* run the launcher.

Comment: Here's the [old FOMM](http://www.nexusmods.com/newvegas/mods/36901/?) - I'm not sure what that "FORK" version is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why my ini edits were not taking effect is because Mod Organizer makes a copy of the original ini files, then uses the copy when launching the game. This is in line with the philosophy of Mod Organizer, that is to not make any destructive changes or to contaminate the original game files.

Here is the button to edit Mod Organizer's copy of the ini file:
[image]

After pasting the same lines here, the new mouse acceleration settings were in effect. There was nothing wrong with Mod Organizer, my fault for not knowing how to use it properly